# Is there any way to reveal enemy health values in The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In Breath of the Wild, wearing the Champion's Tunic (or one of the amiibo-exclusive divine beast helms) caused the current and total health point values to appear over enemy health bars. However, neither the Champion's Leathers nor the Tunic of Memories has this property. It has also been removed from the divine helms. Are there any items or abilities that have this trait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.pcinvasion.com/how-to-see-enemy-health-points-in-zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom/) source, there is no way to see enemy health values with the methods you described.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xe9_sMf0jCM) source seems to say that the reason enemy health values are not in TotK is because the developers skewed the damage numbers for Spears and Great Swords and if they displayed the actual value of damage enemies have taken, players would notice that the UI lies to them saying that Spears do more damage and Great Swords do less damage than they actually do.

Comment: Spears only do 75% of the shown damage value, and Heavy weapons seem to do 20/19 of the of the shown amount.

Comment: Monster Hunter has done a similar thing in the past, so that a big, weighty greatsword doesn't look less powerful than a pair of quick dualblades.